# How to find and store in PHP array all the hours found inside of an SQL database `Datetime` column seperated by day?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, algorithm, datetime

First of all, I am using this piece of code in PHP to retrieve data from a database.

*DATABASE DATA CODE*:

```
// Database Details
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "admin_testdb";
$password = "123412345";
$dbname = "test_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `HOURLY_DATA` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `HOURLY_DATA`.`TIME` ASC";

// Run $sql content as sql script in db.
$result=$conn->query($sql);
```

This code is just fine and has absolutely no errors or problems related to my `goal` here.
Also the specific data table I am looking after in this Query is the table named `TIME` which is of type "Datetime" format in SQL which looks like this:

*DATETIME FORMAT*:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS or to make it more clear an example would be 1970-09-24T05:00:00
```

Now moving onto what I am trying to achieve, my code and then the problem.

*The Goal*:

I have a list of data in the datetime format explained above, where theres `HOURS` missing, the increment of the HOURS is always +1 meaning that an example of missing data inside this data table would be:

```
2021-11-01T00:00:00
2021-11-01T01:00:00
2021-11-01T02:00:00
2021-11-01T05:00:00
2021-11-01T06:00:00
2021-11-01T07:00:00
2021-11-01T08:00:00
2021-11-01T13:00:00
2021-11-01T14:00:00
2021-11-01T15:00:00
2021-11-01T16:00:00
2021-11-01T17:00:00
2021-11-01T18:00:00
2021-11-01T19:00:00
2021-11-01T20:00:00
2021-11-01T21:00:00
```

So by taking a look at this DATETIME list above, we can understand that there is data missing and more specifically hours missing like 22:00:00 or 23:00:00 etc...

Now I want to write a code that will find this missing `HOUR` steps.

So far I have tried this code:

```
// Run $sql content as sql script in db.
$result=$conn->query($sql);
$flag = 0;
$i = 0;
$x = 0;
$cont = array();
$temp = array();
foreach ($result as $value) {
    $singular_value = $value["TIME"];
    $singular_value = str_replace(" ", "", $singular_value);
    $day_value = $singular_value[8].$singular_value[9];
    $day_value = (int) $day_value;
    $singular_value = $singular_value[11].$singular_value[12];
    $singular_value = (int) $singular_value;

    // First time running.
    if ( $flag == 0 ){
        $day_chair = $day_value;
        $flag = 1;
    }

    if ( $day_chair == $day_value ){
        $temp[]= $value["TIME"];
        $cont[$i]= $temp;
        $day_chair = $day_value;
    } else {
        if ( $day_value == 30 || $day_value == 31 ){
            $day_chair = 1;
            continue;
        } else {
            $day_chair += 1;
            $temp = array();
        }
        $i++;
    } 
    
}

print("<pre>".print_r($cont,true)."</pre>");
```

**PROBLEM*:

- To begin with this code returns the hour `00` which is considered to be the 12 o'clock midnight only for the first iteration or day.
- Also the code above is supposed to return and array that will look like this:

  ```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] =>  2021-11-01T00:00:00
                [1] =>  2021-11-01T01:00:00
                [2] =>  2021-11-01T02:00:00
                [3] =>  2021-11-01T03:00:00
                [4] =>  2021-11-01T04:00:00
                [5] =>  2021-11-01T05:00:00
                [6] =>  2021-11-01T06:00:00
                [7] =>  2021-11-01T07:00:00
                [8] =>  2021-11-01T08:00:00
                [9] =>  2021-11-01T09:00:00
                [10] =>  2021-11-01T10:00:00
                [11] =>  2021-11-01T11:00:00
                [12] =>  2021-11-01T12:00:00
                [13] =>  2021-11-01T13:00:00
                [14] =>  2021-11-01T14:00:00
                [15] =>  2021-11-01T15:00:00
                [16] =>  2021-11-01T16:00:00
                [17] =>  2021-11-01T17:00:00
                [18] =>  2021-11-01T18:00:00
                [19] =>  2021-11-01T19:00:00
                [20] =>  2021-11-01T20:00:00
                [21] =>  2021-11-01T21:00:00
                [22] =>  2021-11-01T22:00:00
                [23] =>  2021-11-01T23:00:00
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] =>  2021-11-02T00:00:00
                [1] =>  2021-11-02T01:00:00
                [2] =>  2021-11-02T02:00:00
                [3] =>  2021-11-02T03:00:00
                [4] =>  2021-11-02T04:00:00
                [5] =>  2021-11-02T05:00:00
                [6] =>  2021-11-02T06:00:00
                [7] =>  2021-11-02T07:00:00
                [8] =>  2021-11-02T08:00:00
                [9] =>  2021-11-02T09:00:00
                [10] =>  2021-11-02T10:00:00
                [11] =>  2021-11-02T11:00:00
                [12] =>  2021-11-02T12:00:00
                [13] =>  2021-11-02T13:00:00
                [14] =>  2021-11-02T14:00:00
                [15] =>  2021-11-02T15:00:00
                [16] =>  2021-11-02T16:00:00
                [17] =>  2021-11-02T17:00:00
                [18] =>  2021-11-02T18:00:00
                [19] =>  2021-11-02T19:00:00
                [20] =>  2021-11-02T20:00:00
                [21] =>  2021-11-02T21:00:00
                [22] =>  2021-11-02T22:00:00
                [23] =>  2021-11-02T23:00:00
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] =>  2021-11-03T00:00:00
                [1] =>  2021-11-03T01:00:00
                [2] =>  2021-11-03T02:00:00
                [3] =>  2021-11-03T03:00:00
                [4] =>  2021-11-03T04:00:00
                [5] =>  2021-11-03T05:00:00
                [6] =>  2021-11-03T06:00:00
                [7] =>  2021-11-03T07:00:00
                [8] =>  2021-11-03T08:00:00
                [9] =>  2021-11-03T09:00:00
                [10] =>  2021-11-03T10:00:00
                [11] =>  2021-11-03T11:00:00
                [12] =>  2021-11-03T12:00:00
                [13] =>  2021-11-03T13:00:00
                [14] =>  2021-11-03T14:00:00
                [15] =>  2021-11-03T15:00:00
                [16] =>  2021-11-03T16:00:00
                [17] =>  2021-11-03T17:00:00
                [18] =>  2021-11-03T18:00:00
                [19] =>  2021-11-03T19:00:00
                [20] =>  2021-11-03T20:00:00
                [21] =>  2021-11-03T21:00:00
                [22] =>  2021-11-03T22:00:00
                [23] =>  2021-11-03T23:00:00
            )
    )
  ```

And will leave a `GAP` or simply do write nothing in the array if the date is missing from the database. But this code return a lot of problematic arrays and just to give an example there are some here:

- First day was parsed fine but the second one and all the days after the first day are missing the 12 o'clock aka `00:00:00`

E.X:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  2021-11-01T00:00:00
            [1] =>  2021-11-01T01:00:00
            [2] =>  2021-11-01T02:00:00
            [3] =>  2021-11-01T03:00:00
            [4] =>  2021-11-01T04:00:00
            [5] =>  2021-11-01T05:00:00
            [6] =>  2021-11-01T06:00:00
            [7] =>  2021-11-01T07:00:00
            [8] =>  2021-11-01T08:00:00
            [9] =>  2021-11-01T09:00:00
            [10] =>  2021-11-01T10:00:00
            [11] =>  2021-11-01T11:00:00
            [12] =>  2021-11-01T12:00:00
            [13] =>  2021-11-01T13:00:00
            [14] =>  2021-11-01T14:00:00
            [15] =>  2021-11-01T15:00:00
            [16] =>  2021-11-01T16:00:00
            [17] =>  2021-11-01T17:00:00
            [18] =>  2021-11-01T18:00:00
            [19] =>  2021-11-01T19:00:00
            [20] =>  2021-11-01T20:00:00
            [21] =>  2021-11-01T21:00:00
            [22] =>  2021-11-01T22:00:00
            [23] =>  2021-11-01T23:00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  2021-11-02T01:00:00
            [1] =>  2021-11-02T02:00:00
            [2] =>  2021-11-02T03:00:00
            [3] =>  2021-11-02T04:00:00
            [4] =>  2021-11-02T05:00:00
            [5] =>  2021-11-02T06:00:00
            [6] =>  2021-11-02T07:00:00
            [7] =>  2021-11-02T08:00:00
            [8] =>  2021-11-02T09:00:00
            [9] =>  2021-11-02T10:00:00
            [10] =>  2021-11-02T11:00:00
            [11] =>  2021-11-02T12:00:00
            [12] =>  2021-11-02T13:00:00
            [13] =>  2021-11-02T14:00:00
            [14] =>  2021-11-02T15:00:00
            [15] =>  2021-11-02T16:00:00
            [16] =>  2021-11-02T17:00:00
            [17] =>  2021-11-02T18:00:00
            [18] =>  2021-11-02T19:00:00
            [19] =>  2021-11-02T20:00:00
            [20] =>  2021-11-02T21:00:00
            [21] =>  2021-11-02T22:00:00
            [22] =>  2021-11-02T23:00:00
        )
```

Also, there are broken days for example when the day reaches day 30 or 31 of the month this happens:

```
[28] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  2021-11-29T01:00:00
            [1] =>  2021-11-29T02:00:00
            [2] =>  2021-11-29T03:00:00
            [3] =>  2021-11-29T04:00:00
            [4] =>  2021-11-29T05:00:00
            [5] =>  2021-11-29T06:00:00
            [6] =>  2021-11-29T07:00:00
            [7] =>  2021-11-29T08:00:00
            [8] =>  2021-11-29T09:00:00
            [9] =>  2021-11-29T10:00:00
            [10] =>  2021-11-29T11:00:00
            [11] =>  2021-11-29T12:00:00
            [12] =>  2021-11-29T13:00:00
            [13] =>  2021-11-29T14:00:00
            [14] =>  2021-11-29T15:00:00
            [15] =>  2021-11-29T16:00:00
            [16] =>  2021-11-29T17:00:00
            [17] =>  2021-11-29T18:00:00
            [18] =>  2021-11-29T19:00:00
            [19] =>  2021-11-29T20:00:00
            [20] =>  2021-11-29T21:00:00
            [21] =>  2021-11-29T22:00:00
            [22] =>  2021-11-29T23:00:00
            [23] =>  2021-12-01T00:00:00
            [24] =>  2021-12-01T01:00:00
            [25] =>  2021-12-01T02:00:00
            [26] =>  2021-12-01T03:00:00
            [27] =>  2021-12-01T04:00:00
            [28] =>  2021-12-01T05:00:00
            [29] =>  2021-12-01T06:00:00
            [30] =>  2021-12-01T07:00:00
            [31] =>  2021-12-01T08:00:00
            [32] =>  2021-12-01T09:00:00
            [33] =>  2021-12-01T10:00:00
            [34] =>  2021-12-01T11:00:00
            [35] =>  2021-12-01T12:00:00
            [36] =>  2021-12-01T13:00:00
            [37] =>  2021-12-01T14:00:00
            [38] =>  2021-12-01T15:00:00
            [39] =>  2021-12-01T16:00:00
            [40] =>  2021-12-01T17:00:00
            [41] =>  2021-12-01T18:00:00
            [42] =>  2021-12-01T19:00:00
            [43] =>  2021-12-01T20:00:00
            [44] =>  2021-12-01T21:00:00
            [45] =>  2021-12-01T22:00:00
            [46] =>  2021-12-01T23:00:00
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  2021-12-02T01:00:00
            [1] =>  2021-12-02T02:00:00
            [2] =>  2021-12-02T03:00:00
            [3] =>  2021-12-02T04:00:00
            [4] =>  2021-12-02T05:00:00
            [5] =>  2021-12-02T06:00:00
            [6] =>  2021-12-02T07:00:00
            [7] =>  2021-12-02T08:00:00
            [8] =>  2021-12-02T09:00:00
            [9] =>  2021-12-02T10:00:00
            [10] =>  2021-12-02T11:00:00
            [11] =>  2021-12-02T12:00:00
            [12] =>  2021-12-02T13:00:00
            [13] =>  2021-12-02T14:00:00
            [14] =>  2021-12-02T15:00:00
            [15] =>  2021-12-02T16:00:00
            [16] =>  2021-12-02T17:00:00
            [17] =>  2021-12-02T18:00:00
            [18] =>  2021-12-02T19:00:00
            [19] =>  2021-12-02T20:00:00
            [20] =>  2021-12-02T21:00:00
            [21] =>  2021-12-02T22:00:00
            [22] =>  2021-12-02T23:00:00
        )
```

**QUESTION:**

- What can I do to solve this programmatic/algorithmic problem or what am I doing wrong in my code?